# Is it possible to change SSM Terminal size by using AWS-StartInteractiveCommand

Tags: go, aws-ssm

The terminal size (text indention) is resizing after selecting a node.

I am using this code but it's not working

```
func (smp *SMPClient) createSessionInput(instanceId string) {
    smp.sessionInput = &ssm.StartSessionInput{
        Target:       aws.String(instanceId),
        DocumentName: aws.String("AWS-StartInteractiveCommand"),
        Parameters:   map[string][]string{"command": {"stty rows $ROWS && stty cols $COLUMNS;"}},
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please use tags appropriately. There's nothing related to Ansible nor awx in this question. I removed them. Thanks